# Form send data 2 times

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

i try to record data in DB, but database write blank parameters. Form sent this: site.com/inc/go.php?login=sdfdsf&pass=sddfffds**&login=&pass=** . Why data from form send 2 times?

```
<form id="x" action="/inc/go.php" method=POST">
    <div>
        <span>
            <label for="loginss">
               Login<span class="tcs-form-field-requared">*</span>
            </label>
        </span>

        <span>
            <input type="text" form="x" name="login" id="login" accesskey="n" tabindex="1" id="loginx" title="login" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>
            <label for="passs" class="tcs-form-label">
                password<span>*</span>
            </label>
        </span>

        <span>
            <input class="form-element-hidden form-mobile-hidden" class="form-element-hidden form-mobile-hidden">
            <input form="x" type="password" name="pass" id="pass" accesskey="p" tabindex="2" id="passx" title="pass" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
        </span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>
            <span>lost pass?</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input form="x" class="button" type="submit" tabindex="3" value="log in">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP action file:

```
<?php

    include('connect.php');

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `u825237248_gold` (login , pass) VALUES ('".$_POST['login']."','".$_POST['pass']."')",$db);

?>
```

Comment: Since you're using `method="POST", none of the inputs should be in the URL. That would only happen with `method="GET"`. Is there any Javascript that's submitting the form?

Comment: @barmar , i write GET for show sending data, in script all works correct.

Comment: If you want to see what the form is sending, open up the browser's console and go to the Network tab.

Comment: If the data is being sent twice into the DB is due to you most likely refreshing said php action page. Right after your `mysql_query` I would add a header redirect to your index page this way you avoid refreshing the page. `header('Location: page_togoto.php');`

Comment: @CarlosFerreira He's not saying that the URL is being sent twice, he's saying that the URL has duplicate parameters in it.

Comment: @Barmar oh right, completely misunderstood the question there.

Comment: What is `<input class="form-element-hidden form-mobile-hidden" class="form-element-hidden form-mobile-hidden">` for? I guess it's used by a plugin or framework, maybe it's causing this. What framework is it for?

Comment: @barmar , i dont know. Can i record in DB only parameters with value?

Comment: What do you mean you don't know? This is your HTML, why did you write that if you don't know what it means?

Comment: If you have two parameters with the same name, the last one becomes the value in `$_GET` or `$_POST`. You need to figure out where the extra input is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

```
<form id="x" action="/inc/go.php" method=POST">
change <form id="x" action="/inc/go.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: if you use get method then you should use $_GET['login']